# Composite index required does not exist, yet defined in index.yaml

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I have some IoT devices that are sending some data into a Google Cloud Datastore.

The Datastore is setup as Cloud Firestore in Datastore mode.

Each row has the following fields:

- Name/ID
- current_temperature
- data
- device_id
- event
- gc_pub_sub_id
- published_at
- target_temperature

And these are all under the `ParticleEvent` kind.

I wish to run the following query; `select current_temperature, target_temperature from ParticleEvent where device_id = ‘abc123’ order by published_at desc`.

I get the below error when I try to run that query:

> GQL query error: Your Datastore does not have the composite index (developer-supplied) required for this query.

So I setup an `index.yaml` file with the following contents:

```
indexes:

- kind: ParticleEvent
  properties:
  - name: data
  - name: device_id
  - name: published_at
    direction: desc

- kind: ParticleEvent
  properties:
  - name: current_temperature
  - name: target_temperature
  - name: device_id
  - name: published_at
    direction: desc
```

I used the `gcloud` tool to send this successfully up to the datastore and I can see both indexes in the indexes tab.

However I still get the above error when I try to run the query.

What do I need to add/change to my indexes to get this query to work?

Comment: the error message does not suggest the correct index you should build?

Comment: @Ogbe Nope. It just includes a link to a help page on creating indexes, which is what I used to create the above.

Comment: Datastore is weird when you want to choose specific columns, try simply `select * from ParticleEvent order by published_at desc`, and make an index **only** for `published_at` with `desc`.

Comment: @MatrixTai I can run that kind of query without a composite index at all. I was able to run that query as soon as my datastore had rows in it. I had missed a where condition in my query which I have added now. I want to be able to select specific columns with a where condition and order by.

Comment: Still the same idea, never select specific columns. Just index `published_at` and `device_id` this case. I understand that's sound non-sense, but that's way how to solve it.

Comment: @MatrixTai it sounds non-sense but you're right, it does work! It seems silly that this is the case, but so be it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though in the comment I simply suggest `select *` (that's the best way, I do think)

There is a way make your query work.

```
- kind: ParticleEvent
  properties:
  - name: device_id
  - name: published_at
    direction: desc
  - name: current_temperature
  - name: target_temperature
```

The reason why is `select` is done at the end and thus you need the index of `current_temperature` and `target_temperature` in a lower level.

---

Why I don't suggest this way is because, when your data grows and you need more combination of indexing **just because of** `select` specific columns. Your index size will grow exponentially.

But let's say if you sure you will just use this once and **always** query the data like this, then feel free to indexing it.

Or, if the connection bandwidth between your computer and google cloud is very small such that downloading more data causes you lag.

Comment: Thanks. This is very useful. It’s not overly intuitive that it works this way, but thanks for your help!